# Developing for android with visual studio and Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to develop an app for android using Xamarin Studio which adds the possibility to do that. So i created a new project and didn't add anything just compiled the solution and the android emulator only shows a black screen. I didn't do anything so is there something missing? I've installed everything recommended by the installer..

My Visual Studio version is Visual Studio Community

Comment: Hint: you didnt add anything. What did you expect to see?

Comment: @BenKnoble The new project with Xamarin create a Hello World button.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if the template for an Android project does the hello world, but I am sure that the Xamarin Forms template has that, are you perhaps confusing the two?

Comment: Visual studio emulator for android is buggy (at least on my machine) try clicking on the activity title, or in the position where the button should be, it might be there but just not rendered properly (on device it should work)

Comment: @kirotab I think Xamarin sucks haha i will go and do my app with Java ^^

Comment: @user5014677 well I reserve my opinion, not enough experience with the technology. It's a little bit buggy, but with the right project could be the right choice. And btw if my suggestion is correct it's not related to Xamarin but rather to the VS Android Emulator.

Comment: @kirotab I tried runing the project and clicking where the button is supposed to be. The untouched solution does nothing. So i added an alert and it does nothing either. I tried sending my apk to my phone it does nothing. If i can't even debug a simple "Hello world" function i'm not into developing with such a buggy extension. I don't get how can there be nothing to develop android apps on visual studio.

Comment: @user5014677 hm, It might require some additional setup, if it's not stopping on breakpoints in your activity for example, try checking if you're running in debug mode etc... I've got to say it's not very polished, but it's as bad as it seems the first time you try it :) .If you only have to do an Android version of your app it would be less pain to just do it native though.

Comment: Can you post the code that was generated for the activity?  It's possible that a small error has occurred (such as not setting a start-up activity).  People here will be able to help more with code.